# Trying to scrape the Youtube Statistics for a video not owned by me. Python

Tags: python, youtube

I want to  **scrape** the "average duration watched" for a video not owned by me, using Scrapy.

While parsing the page `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#########`, the data does not load. This is expected because, it seems to be a ajax call.
I didn't find an API that does the trick.

In the XHR, the POST request sent is

> http://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=OoWSnDmeqAs

In the POST response I can see the details of data, but when I hit it a separate tab, I don't see any data. In [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937537/youtube-video-statistics) the user *beeglebug* did try to mention something.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: may be this will help:http://quvi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The URL you provided is correct, but opening it in a separate tab won't work, because it should go with some session cookies and post data with session token. You will see that if you inspect the request in FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, you may try the add-on "Shelve", in autoexecution mode. Then ask your firefox to load the relevant youtube page, perhaps automatically, and it will automatically be saved with the information you want. I don't know how automatic you want the result, your question is not precise enough about that.

auto-execution is called "Auto-Shelve" ; you may want to edit the pattern of files saved automatically.